# Preventing HTML canvas object selection

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm customising my homepage with an interactive animation, but having trouble making it feel more seemelss in the page. Please see http://geotheory.co.uk/.  I want to stop the canvas object from being selected when the user clicks on the page. The animation is a [Processing script](http://geotheory.co.uk/rectangles.pde) that is then [translated](http://geotheory.co.uk/processing-1.4.1.min.js) to javascript.  The index.html reads:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>geotheory.co.uk</title>
</head>
<body  id="home" bgcolor="#202020">
    <script src="processing-1.4.1.min.js"></script>
    <div id="canvasContainer">
    <canvas padding: 0 data-processing-sources="rectangles.pde"></canvas>
    </div>
</body>
```

Grateful for assistance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is the :focus pseduo class that is causing it. This should fix it:

```
canvas:focus{
    outline:none;
}
```